# how to retrieve the previous row value using linq query?

Tags: c#

I want to retrieve the previous row value for transnett and obnett to update the current row based on the StackHistoryID so whether the above query works?

```
var val = (from tn in db.tablename.ToList()
           where tn.ID.ToString() != currentID.ToString()
           orderby tn.TransactionDate descending
           group tn by tn.StackHistoryID into trans
           select new {
               transnett=trans.Select(t=>t.TransNett),
               obnett=trans.Select(t=>t.OBNett)
           }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: "Previous" implies an order - "previous" ordered by what criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns the latest row assuming TransactionDate always has a value and was set correctly. Is that what you want or do you want the row before that?

I think you query looks better like:

```
var rows = from tn in db.tablename
           where tn.ID != currentID
           orderby tn.TransactionDate descending
           group tn by tn.StackHistoryID into trans
           select new {transnett=trans.Select(t=>t.TransNett),obnett=trans.Select(t=>t.OBNett)});

var previousRow = rows.first();
```

Comment: I want to add the previous row transnett and obnett value and update the answer in the obnett field but for the current row, how can i add transnett and obnett

Comment: sorry there are too many variables there I do not know about - I will need more - what do you want the add to? what field in obnett do you want to update? do you want to update a database or just the object in memory? what to object look like?

Comment: Now i am retrieving the values from the obnett field and transnett field from the table tablename know, so i need to add both obtained values like for example tablename.obnett = val.transnett + val.obnett but it is giving me error since i cant use '+' operator while adding 2 objects. so how can i add?

Comment: of course you can't. your table is called "tablename"!? I think perhaps you copied that from somewhere - you need to replace it with you table name! I don't know the types you are using but the table might have an add method, e.g. obnetTable.Add(obnet). However it looks like you are learning - I cannot teach you - consult the documentation or read a book on it, im afraid I can help you no more, good luck!